# Gems and artifacts missing

Tags: temple-run-2

I am on level 9, and my challenges are collect all 10 rings and relic artifacts, and to collect 5 gems in one run. However, there don't seem to be any artifacts or gems to collect anymore, and I haven't seen any for almost a week and a half. I have run between 2 million and 5 million, and still nothing.

What can I do to move on?

Comment: I've cleaned up your question a bit to make it easier to understand; please let me know if I've accidentally changed the meaning of the question you're trying to ask somehow.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to find any gems!

Unlocked at Level 8, you can change your bonus meter to award gems every time you fill it up.
To change the power up the meter gives, select "Power up" on the character selection menu, and the select "Gems".

Power ups (like gems) obtained this way still count towards daily missions and multiplier objectives.

**Essentially, fill the bonus meter five times with the gem power up equipped.**

> I can't seem to find any artefacts!

*It seems like RNGesus wasn't on your side...*

Artefacts are a rare power up. You can increase your chances by levelling up your "Pickup Spawn Chance" passive. When upgraded to Level 6, it increases the spawn chance by 30%.

Alternatively, play on the limited time maps (unlocked with 500 gems outside event), as they have greater chances of spawning Relic Chests. While these chests mostly contain the level's relic set, it also has a chance to spawn regular artefacts.

Answer (score -1):

This had happened with me too...I purposely ended the game by tripping twice or jumping into the air for 3-4 games near a 100,000 points.You could try completing daily challenges consecutively for the 5th days reward too.Hope it works for you :)
For gems, just use gem power in power ups.

Comment: Fifth and up day chest rewards only contain gems and coins.